# How to make a generalized use from multiple array

Tags: android, arrays

I'm creating an android app which has selection of company and based on that I show cars and based on selection of particular car, I want to show some details of car e.g. capacity, power, engine oil etc. Now I'm using array to store all this car related information. e.g.

```
private static final String[] car1={"624CC","33bhp","10W40"}
private static final String[] car2={"1600CC","120bhp","10W40"}
```

To check the section, I've used multiple if-else statements for each car. And depending on the selection, I show value form array.

```
 if(bn.equals("car 1"))
    {
        cap.setText(""+car1[0]);
        powr.setText(""+car1[1]);
        oil.setText(" "+car1[2]);
    }
    else if(bn.equals("car 2"))
    {
        cap.setText(""+car2[0]);
        powr.setText(""+car2[1]);
        oil.setText(" "+car2[2]);
    }
    else if(bn.equals("car 3"))
    {
        cap.setText(""+car3[0]);
        powr.setText(""+car3[1]);
        oil.setText(" "+car3[2]);
    }
```

Now the problem is as the number of if-else have increased,I'm getting error of "Code too large" in android studio. 
I was wondering if is there any way to replace these multiple if else statements with single, generalised statement. As you can see, in all if else, the code is the same, its just that array name is different. 
I'm aware that I can use SQLite db, but I'll have to add all the values to it for all the cars again. So was wondering if I can use the same array that I've created. Any solution/suggestion will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Probably in place of string comparison of names you can store the index of the value selected and use switch case to find out which car is selected. This should reduce the code also make it much more readable.